# Why is pci_msi_enable function deprecated yet still callable within 5.4 linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pci/msi.c#L1130

-In the above link, I see that `pci_enable_msi` function is deprecated, but I can still call it successfully in my driver. Why is it deprecated? What is a good replacement?

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSI Driver Guide HOWTO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/msi-howto.html#using-msi):

> Most of the hard work is done for the driver in the PCI layer. The driver simply has to request that the PCI layer set up the MSI capability for this device.
>
> To automatically use MSI or MSI-X interrupt vectors, use the following function:
>
> ```
> int pci_alloc_irq_vectors(struct pci_dev *dev, unsigned int min_vecs,
>              unsigned int max_vecs, unsigned int flags);
> ```

Looking at the source we can see `pci_enable_msi` calls `__pci_enable_msi_range(dev, 1, 1, NULL)` (see [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.196/source/drivers/pci/msi.c#L1151)).

This same function is called in `pci_alloc_irq_vectors` and `pci_alloc_irq_vectors_affinity` (see [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.196/source/drivers/pci/msi.c#L1255) and [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.196/source/include/linux/pci.h#L1779)).